# How do I pip install packages in a conda environment.yml file?

Tags: python, conda

I get the following error when I run the below code:

```
name: myapp-env
dependencies:
- python=3.5
- pip
- django=1.8
- pip:
    - django-environ=0.4
```

Error:

```
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
found character '\t' that cannot start any token
  in "<string>", line 7, column 1:
        - django-environ=0.4
```

What is the proper way to format the .yml file to pip install a package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite explicit there: YAML (as implemented in pyyaml) forbids the use of tab-characters for indentation. Change that line to `<space><space><space><space>- django-environ=0.4`.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed my problem. I was using Sublime text and Indentation was set to Tab. I selected `Convert Indentation to Spaces` and it worked.

Also, the .yml file should be as follows (two == for pip package version).

```
name: myapp-env
dependencies:
- python=3.5
- pip
- django=1.8
- pip:
    - django-environ==0.4
```